# can not find the image for ubuntu touch 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch

I am trying to flash ubuntu touch 14.04 to nexus 5, however, as I flash according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices, the default version is vivid (15.04), and I took a look at the corresponding server (http://system-image.tasemnice.eu), there is no any 14.04 related resource at all.

Anybody any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It does not exist.

From the downloads:

> **Ubuntu Touch**
>
> As part of the wider Ubuntu 14.04 release efforts the
>   Ubuntu Touch team is proud to make the latest and greatest touch
>   experience available to our enthusiast users and developers.
>
> While this Ubuntu Touch release is still not a supported release, we
>   feel it is important to hand out a relatively "stable" build for wider
>   testing and feedback while we are continuing with high velocity
>   towards our going-to-market milestone late this summer. Also, while
>   not product quality yet, this image is a big step forward feature-wise
>   compared to our initial release done in October 2013, so we hope you
>   will enjoy using this on your phone and tablet.
>
> **Devices**
>
> For this milestone we added tablets to the mix of devices we offer
>   builds for. The set of devices with builds available is:
>
> - Nexus 4 Phone (mako)
> - Nexus 7 (2013) Tablet (flo)
> - Nexus 10 Tablet (manta)

There is no 14.04 touch for a Nexus 5.